# how to convert Jquery line of codes into vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

new to Vue, trying to implement previously JS + JQuery code in Vue

I have this List:

```
    <ul id="progressbar">
    <li class="active">integration Ip's</li>
    <li>Traffic Details</li>
    <li>API Creds</li>
  </ul>
```

Every time next/previous button is pressed, the "active" class moves to another list element, for example:

```
isNextClicked() {
            var nextStage = this.currentPage;
            this.currentPage++;
            console.log("CurrentPage =>", this.currentPage);
            $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(nextStage)).addClass("active"); //Convert this to vue
            return this.currentPage;
        },
```

How can I convert this:

```
$("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(nextStage)).addClass("active");
```

Into vue synax?

Photo of the progress bar:

[image: progressbar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to convert anything. You just need to read the first few chapters in the Vue documentation.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      active: 1,
      step: ['step 1', 'step 2', 'step 3'],
    }
  },
})
```

```css
.activeClass{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li
      v-for="(items, index) in step"
      :key="items"
      :class="(index === active) ? 'activeClass' : ''"
      v-text="items"
    />
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, this almost working for me, the progress bar is showing that I'm on page 1 when I'm on page 3

Comment: Just change the `active` variable and you will get what you need.